# Show each x-value on the plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

[image]
So I have these two dictionaries A and B. I want to plot both to compare with each other which I have done here. But I want to make sure on the x-axis, each value is showing i.e. all the keys of the dictionaries are showing. How do I get to do this?

Comment: All keys are displayed in the figure - if there is an entry in any of the two dictionaries, it will be plotted. What exactly do you expect differently? Also: Don't post code/data as images. Post that information as a text.

Comment: See, how the x axis values are at an interval of 20? I want to remove this and instead show the exact keys from the dictionary, I mean, I want the years to show for each bar.

Answer (score 0):

This will be rather busy if you label every bar position. Are you sure you want to do this? It is not complicated to collect all dictionary keys and plot them as x-ticks but you may be disappointed by the outcome:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

A = {1: 2, 3: 4, 8: 6, 10: 8}
B = {1: 23, 4: 6, 10: 9}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(A.keys(), A.values(), width=0.3, align="edge", label="male")
ax.bar(B.keys(), B.values(), width=-0.3, align="edge", label="female")

#collect all dictionary keys
all_keys=set(list(A.keys()) + list(B.keys()))

#set ticks where dictionary keys exist and rotate them because of space problems
#plt.xticks(list(all_keys), rotation=90)
#or if you want to use the ax object instead
ax.set_xticks(list(all_keys))
ax.tick_params(axis="x", labelrotation=90)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Sample output
[image]